# Зачем нужна функция сравнения элементов у std::unordered_set?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, хеширование, множества

Если для добавления элементов в `std::unordered_set` нужна только функция хеширования, а функция сравнения элементов не учитывается, то для чего `std::unordered_set` её хранит?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>
#include <unordered_set>


struct Custom {
    std::string a, b, c;

    // only first 2 fields are significant
    friend bool operator==(const Custom& lhs, const Custom& rhs) {
        return lhs.a == rhs.a &&
               lhs.b == rhs.b;
    }
};

namespace std {

template<>
struct hash<Custom> {
    std::size_t operator()(const Custom& custom) const noexcept {
        // but wanna hash for every field
        const std::array strings = {custom.a, custom.b, custom.c};

        std::hash<std::string> hasher;
        std::size_t hash = 0;
        for (auto&& string : strings) {
            hash ^= hasher(string) + 0x9e3779b9 + (hash << 6) + (hash >> 2);
        }

        return hash;
    }
};

}


int main() {
    Custom x_1 = {"1", "2", "3"};
    Custom x_2 = {"1", "2", "whatever"};
    std::cout << (x_1 == x_2) << '\n'; // x_2 is considered equal to x_1

    std::unordered_set<Custom> set{x_1, x_2};

    std::cout << set.size(); // but looks like operator == is not considered at all
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что у разных объектов может быть одно и то же хеш-значение. И тогда, чтобы найти нужный элемент, выполняется поиск среди всех элементов множества с соответствующих хешем, но уже с использованием сравнения самих элементов.

Простоты для - мы кладем в множество с хеш-функцией `x%5` числа 2, 7 и 12. А потом ищем в нем число 17. Есть ли оно там? Хеш-значение будет такое же - 2, как и у 2, 7 и 12. Но выяснить, что там нет 17, можно только путем сравнения самих значений, а не хешей.

Comment: В таком случае сложность поиска будет линейной, а не константной?

Comment: В вырожденном случае - несомненно.