# Почему std::unordered_set принимает функцию сравнения двух элементов на равенство, а не отношение меньше?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, хеширование, множества

Почему `std::unordered_set` принимает функцию сравнения двух элементов на равенство, а не отношение меньше? Ведь в таком случае можно вывести при необходимости равенство как `!(a<b)&&!(b<a)`, а также отсортировать ключи с одинаковым значением хеш-функции, чтобы потом выполнять не линейный поиск в бакете, а бинарный.

Comment: отсортировать ключи с одинаковым значением хеш-функции никак не получится, поскольку речь идет об  std::unordered_set, который хранит только уникальные элементы (их значения не могут быть одинаковыми), а  сравнение на равенства двух элементов  исходит из логики того, что  иное сравнение не  нужно в контейнере

Comment: @ARHovsepyan значения элементов могут быть одинаковыми, смотрите [мой предыдущий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/914408/Зачем-нужна-функция-сравнения-элементов-у-stdunordered-set?rq=1)

Comment: Не понимаю на что мне смотреть, если по факту  std::unordered_set  не является  контейнером  std::unordered_multiset...  Из них только второй может иметь элементы с одинаковым значением.      А если вы все таки хотите  доказывать обратное, Бог вам в помощь...

Comment: Значения хэша могут быть одинаковым, но значения обьектов разные, а отсортировать их  как вы собираетесь непонятно...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отношение "меньше" более строгое (строгое слабое упорядочение, поищите в Гугле - RuSO не разрешает ссылку вставить...), чем отношение равенства (ну, например, детскую игру "бумага-ножницы-камень" знаете? Равенство есть, а нормального отношения "меньше" - нет). Это наложило бы лишнее ограничение на хранимые данные, при том, что выигрыша в скорости практически не дало бы (подробнее всю математику хеширования см. в книгах Кнута, например, или Кормена - здесь всю ее расписывать смысла нет).

При хорошей хеш-функции получаем время поиска O(1), ну, а если функция такая, что вопрос уже встает о том, чтобы искать значение бинарным поиском - то проще использовать обычный `set`...